# Adding two instance groups to one backend service

Tags: load-balancing, google-cloud-platform

On Google Cloud, is it possible to add two instance groups to one backend service ? :/

Answer (score 0):

Yep,you should create the backend-service first [1] then add the two instance-group one by one[2].That can be achieved by running the two below command:

```
$gcloud compute backend-services create BACKEND_SERVICE_NAME  

$gcloud compute backend-services add-backend BACKEND_SERVICE_NAME --instance-group=INSTANCE_GROUP
```

[1]https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/backend-services/create

[2]https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/backend-services/add-backend